# Add Android Fragments dynamically

Tags: android, android-fragments

I created a new fragment that holds two other fragments a right and a left fragment. I called this fragment GridFragment. When i dynamically add GridFragments only the last added fragment is shown. It looks like my GridFragment instance is reused every time I add it. Any ideas why this happens?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:weightSum="1.0"><FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/left_fragment"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:layout_width="0dip">
</FrameLayout>
<FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/right_fragment"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.5"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        >
</FrameLayout>
```

```
public class GridFragment extends Fragment {
private FragmentManager fm;
private FragmentTransaction ft;
private Fragment leftFragment;
private Fragment rightFragment;

private boolean isLeftFragmentSet = false;
private boolean isRightFragmentSet = false;

public GridFragment(Fragment leftFragment, Fragment rightFragment) {
    this.leftFragment = leftFragment;
    this.rightFragment = rightFragment;
}

public Fragment getLeftFragment() {
    return leftFragment;
}

public Fragment getRightFragment() {
    return rightFragment;
}

public boolean isLeftFragmentSet() {
    return isLeftFragmentSet;
}

public boolean isRightFragmentSet() {
    return isRightFragmentSet;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_fragment, container, false);

    fm = getFragmentManager();

    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.left_fragment, leftFragment, leftFragment.toString()).commit();
    fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.right_fragment, rightFragment, rightFragment.toString()).commit();

    return rootView;
}

public void setLeftFragment(Fragment fragment){
    leftFragment = fragment;
    isLeftFragmentSet = true;
}

public void setRightFragment(Fragment fragment){
    rightFragment = fragment;
    isRightFragmentSet = true;
}
}
```

I want to use this to get a screen filled with wide fragments and two smaller fragments alternately.
Here is an example of what I want to achieve:

[image: Grid]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see in your code fundamental mistakes.

First of all `rootView` is not part of your `Activity` layout at the time when you request left and right fragments to be added by `FragmentManager` which is looking for `R.id.left_fragment` inside `Activity` layout.

Secondly, if you want nest fragments within fragment you have to use `getChildFragmentManager()` instead `getFragmentManager()`. Also make use of `FragmentTransaction` chain builder, so instead:

```
fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.left_fragment, leftFragment, leftFragment.toString()).commit();
fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.right_fragment, rightFragment, rightFragment.toString()).commit();
```

call:

```
fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.left_fragment, leftFragment, leftFragment.toString())
    .add(R.id.right_fragment, rightFragment, rightFragment.toString())
    .commit();
```

Maybe you should consider placing your fragments directly inside `Activity` layout and replace your `GridFragment` with [GridLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridLayout.html).

Comment: Thanks Loop the your suggestions did the trick. Everything works as it should.